# html Text Editor Ajax control tool kit

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using html editor from ajax control tool kit. When i get the content its giving me an html content withe all the formatting tags is it possible to get the preview content from this control. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The preview is just an iframe that has been filled with the content html at the client side. There isn't really a "value" for the content other than this. If you just wanted the text you can probably parse this out of the content.

I think the content from this control is always well-formed (just did some testing [here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx)), so you can use xml:

```
//Load up the xml document
System.Xml.XmlDocument xml = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXML(myHTMLEditor.Content.replace("&nbsp;","")); //Replace entities with ""

//Get all the text
string s = xml.InnerText;
```

Note that this won't work in general for html - just the output from this control.

Comment: @John: How can i parse the content from the html editor. Can you please show me some sample.

Comment: let me try and let you know i have not used xml so it will take some time to do that. Thanks for the support.